# Finding certain strings in array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, string

I'm having a problem in searching in an array. I wanted to check if a certain string 
exists in one of the elements, example

Array:

```
["4_1", "4_2", "4_3"]
```

I will check if the string "4" exists in one of the variables.

Thank you!

Comment: `STRING.indexOf(needle)` in a loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Easiest way is to use `Array.prototype.join` && `indexOf` methods

`["4_1", "4_2", "4_3"].join("").indexOf("4")`

***Update***

According to @t.niese's comment this answer may cause wrong result, for example if you are looking for `14` it will return `2` - what is wrong because your array doesnt contain element which begins on `14`. In this case better to use @Nina's answer or you can join it in another way 
`["4_1", "4_2", "4_3"].join("  ").indexOf("14") // -1`

Comment: The performance might not be the best for larger arrays, and will also have a problem, if the OP decides to use a string with more then on char as `needle` , because  it will then give a false positive for `["4_1", "4_2", "4_3"].join("").indexOf("14")`.

Comment: For all `.join` it will be possible to find a failure case: `["4_1", "4_2", "4_3"].join(separator).indexOf("1"+separator+"4")`  will show a result. If the OP really only looks for numbers, then it will work. But because the question itself is only a generic `[...]I wanted to check if a certain string exists in one of the elements[...]` then under this conditions a `.join` will never be a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a loop for it.

```js
var arr = ["4_1", "4_2", "4_3"];
    search = RegExp(4),
    result = arr.some(search.test.bind(search));

document.write(result);
```

Comment: I do not fully grasp the need for the complexity of your code. Why be case insensitive on a number and why the bind?

Comment: The `some` is really good. Yes, why case insensitive on a number?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, it was for future reference ... ;)

Comment: @mplungjan, try it without bind, it does not work outside of a function around.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make a loop and check the `indexOf` to be not `-1`:

```js
["4_1", "4_2", "4_3"].forEach(function (element, index, array) {
  if (element.indexOf(4) != -1)
    alert("Found in the element #" + index + ", at position " + element.indexOf(4));
});
```